# BJT voltage divider bias problem

Tags: resistors, bjt, voltage-divider, bias

[image]

Hi I am having trouble with how to find Req of the resistor network of the bjt circuit on the schematic. How can I calculate it to find Ib Vb values? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi Oggy, welcome to EE.SE. Use Kirchoff's voltage and current laws (KVL and KCL) to analyze the circuit. You'll likely end up with N equations and N unknowns, and then you can solve for the unknowns. And please edit your question to show us the work you've done so far to answer this (homework?) problem.

Comment: Hi Jim thanks for advice but I cant determine Req of resistor network abobe the base. I need to simplify like R2//R5 then its parallel to R5 or R1? Besides I dont know current values

Comment: Hi, oggy: you can’t really simplify this like you want to, because of the transistor collector connection to where r4and r5 are connected. You are going to have to use nodal analysis, as Jim suggested, and crank it out.

Comment: Recall that to find the Thevenin equivalent resistance you (a) disconnect the load, and (b) set all independent sources to zero. Is the voltage at the top of resistor R4 an independent voltage source? It is not. So Thevenin's theorem can't be used to analyze this particular circuit (at least, not as you were hoping to). You'll need to use KCL and KVL. And you are correct that you don't yet know the branch currents--but you don't need to know them. You'll solve for the node voltages and then use that information to solve the branch currents.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt understand. how can I simplify by using KVL KCL

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with KCL and KVL, you'll need to learn these concepts. There are some good YouTube videos and websites that provide useful information on these circuit analysis techniques to get you started. Personally, I would use KCL to analyze this circuit, which yields the node voltages. Once the node voltages are known, it's possible to solve for the branch currents.

Comment: (P.S. I misspelled "Kirchhoff" in my first comment.)

Comment: (P.P.S. Other relevant terms to search for are "nodal analysis" and "loop analysis".)

Comment: Ok let me do then I will post here thanks

Comment: I added equations Is that correct?

Comment: I have still problem that should I take Ib=0 also ı need to know Vcb voltages right?

Comment: Can someone help please?